# cursor within a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, cursor

I am trying to make a cursor inside a trigger and the result of the cursor allows me to make inserts in another table, but I have problems with the NEW.id, I think that when I entered the cursor this parameter became empty .. how could it fix it?

when I send a static data it works without problem

I appreciate your help.

```
 BEGIN          
             DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;                        
             DECLARE _ingredient_id INTEGER;            
             DECLARE _unit_cost decimal(11,2);
             DECLARE _quantity INTEGER;                                                         

            DECLARE items CURSOR FOR
            SELECT ingredients.id,ingredients.unit_cost,recipes.quantity 
            FROM sales, orders,detail_orders,recipes,ingredients 
            WHERE sales.id = NEW.id 
            AND orders.sale_id= NEW.id 
            AND detail_orders.order_id=orders.id            
            AND detail_orders.food_id=recipes.food_id           
            AND recipes.ingredient_id=ingredients.id;
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;            

            OPEN items;            
             getItems: LOOP
            FETCH items INTO _ingredient_id,_unit_cost,_quantity;            
             IF finished = 1 THEN                               
                LEAVE getItems;             
             END IF;            

              SET @total= _unit_cost*_quantity;            
             INSERT INTO inventories (type,date,ingredient_id,quantity,unit_cost,total,sale_id) VALUES (2,now(),_ingredient_id,_quantity,_unit_cost,@total,NEW.id);                  

             END LOOP getItems;  
             CLOSE items;    
END
```

Comment: could you add tables and data, and insert or update that you use so it is not to reproduce your problem

Comment: Why do you use a cursor in the first place? Your select + insert can be replaced by a single insert ... select ... query. What type of trigger is this? Before or after insert?

Comment: thanks for the answers, I managed to solve the problem with a procedure

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem with a stored procedure